# How do you successfully setup .netcore app in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core, libstdc++

Trying to run `sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1` gives me 2 dependency.

[image]

I'm not sure how to get rid of these dependency to make my .netcore app work online. I have the newest version of libstdc.

Comment: All code, logs and console I/O should be pasted here (and everywhere on the web) as text, not images. Would you fix that in your post please? You can post formatted I/O by pasting in the text, selecting it, and clicking the `{}` code button.

Comment: I manage to install it without any problem just following the instructions in the documentation